# Pulling the most recent data from underlying table in Django

Tags: django, oracle, django-models

I'm new to Django and don't have much experience in coding. I'm a bit confused about how it actually talks to databases.

I'm trying to take a stab at building a dashboard that will display a table. The data comes from an Oracle database, and the table I'm particularly interested in is being constantly updated outside of Django. It's a living object and I would like the dashboard to display the "current state" of that table on page load. My understanding is that Django models will not help here because what Django displays is the state the table has been in during the last migration/sync, correct? Am I stuck with raw sql then? Is there even a point in creating models in this case?

On top of that I would love to be able to update/delete rows in the table from the dashboard itself but I'm not sure how to do that when the underlying Oracle table is changing every couple of minutes. Am I thinking about this incorrectly?

Thanks!

Comment: Migration/sync is only for the schema, not data, so as long as the schemas don't change you can still use your models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work with [unmanaged](http://official%20page) tables in Django just fine. If you want your view to display the latest values in the table, you can sort the queryset in descending order:

```
Obj.objects.all().order_by('-id')
```

> On top of that I would love to be able to update/delete rows in the table from the dashboard itself but I'm not sure how to do that when the underlying Oracle table is changing every couple of minutes.

This is not the issue. You still can PUT, POST, and DELETE on your API (models) as long as underlying schemas don't change.